# Number of cells in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps, limits

A google spreadsheet has a limit of 2.000.000 cells. Is there a way to find out how large your spreadsheet is at any time?
So you can take action whenever the limit is almost reached....

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to write a custom function in google apps script that returns the number of cells for the current spreadsheet.

```
function numberOfCells() {
return SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheets()
    .reduce(function (pr, cu) {
        return pr + (cu.getMaxColumns() * cu.getMaxRows());
    }, 0)
}
```

Add the above to the script editor then in the spreadsheet use the custom formula like so:

```
=numberOfCells()
```

Hope that helps ?